# Extract structures in a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, save, structure

I have a structure ('data'), with 26 fields (A, B, C, D, etc.). Each field contains 1x30 cells (one for each participant), and each cell contains a structure. 
I would like to extract all the structures (i.e., one structure per field) corresponding to each participant. That is, I would like to obtain 30 new ‘data’, each with 26 fields, and each field containing 1x1 structure, with the structure corresponding to the participant. I have tried the following code:

```
data = load('D:\filepath\mydata.mat'); %load file with data. 1x1 struct.
all_fields = fieldnames(data); %store the fields of the structure. 26x1 cell.

forStr = length(all_fields); %26
n_ppts = 30; %total number of participants.

%for each participant, extract the corresponding structure in each field.
for nn = 1:n_ppts 
    for idx_field = 1:forStr
        name_field = all_fields{idx_field};
        data2 = data;
        data2.(name_field) = data.(name_field){nn};
    end

    %save the 'data' for each participant. The 'data' should include 26 fields, and 1 structure for each field.
    name = ppt_fname(nn);  %Generate the new name for saving
    savename =string(regexprep(name,'_oldname.set','_newname.mat'));
    save(savename, '-struct', 'data');
end
```

The code doesn’t give any error. However, it doesn’t run as I expected.
‘data2’ still contains 26 fields, but only the last field contains 1 structure corresponding to the participant. The other fields contain 1x30 cell.
I guess it is because every time I run the loop it overwrites the previous fields, leaving only the last field correct. So, I think I might need a temporary variable where to store each iteration of the loop.

I thought to create as the temporary storage for each field

```
structure = [];
namelist = {‘A’;’B’;’C’;’D’;’E’;’F’;’G’;’H’;’I’;’J’;’K’;’L’;’M’;’N’;’O’;’P’;’Q’;’R’;’S’;’T’;’U’;’V’;’W’;’X’;’Y’;’Z’};
for i = 1:length(namelist)
    structure.(namelist{i})={};
end
```

But cannot figure out how to make it work.

Comment: **Do not repost questions which have been closed**. Your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60167379/3978545) got closed for a reason, deleting it to subvert the system is not acceptable, you should improve it per the comments you were given so it could get re-opened. You could have at least added a [mcve] to make this answerable, rather than kind-of adopting one of my suggestions and posting the same question.

Comment: The code now works, does not give errors as in the previous question I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the line `data2 = data;` out of the for loops.

Comment: If I remove that line, the `data` correctly displays one structure for each field, but the loops breaks giving this error: `Brace indexing is not supported for variables of this type. Error in newname (line 30) data.(name_field) = data.(name_field){nn};`.

Comment: I see what you mean now.  If I place `data2=data;` after the first `for` but before the second `for`. If you change your answer accordingly, I will select it as accepted solution. Thanks very much!
`for nn = 1:n_ppts
    data2 = data;
    for idx_field = 1:forStr
        %code%
    end
        %code%
end`

Answer (score 0):

Antoine T is right, you always copy the original structure `data` again to `data2` in every loop. That is why it won't get changed (except for the very last step of the loop, where you add a single field name to it.)

Regarding your other problem:

```
% create empty struct:
S = struct();
% loop
for i = 1:25
    % create field name
    nm = char( double('A') +i );
    % create new field with empty cell.
    S.(nm) = {};
end
```

It is just nice to convert number to chars as fieldnames. Your primary error was that you used the wrong inverted comma to create chars.
A minor flaw though was that you allocated `strucutre = []` as an empty matrix rather than as an empty struct